# How to compile c code in Android project without header-file?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

I have a library with c code, and I want to compile it to a .so lib with NDK, but when I run ndk-build command, it needs header file and there is no header file in that library, only dot c.

There are so many source files, and how can I achieve this with it?
Is there a way to compile it without header-file?
Or maybe generate them in batches?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot compile a c/cpp file without having access to the header files it requires. Some default header files are usually provided by the corresponding stdlibc which ships with the compiler you use. Others you have to provide yourself by installing their libraries in appropriate paths or giving their path explicitly during compilation.

Generally header files are included by the pre-processor, prior to compilation, as they provide some functionality which is required by the code within the c file (except when they are pointless includes).

Comment: thank your an answer. 
so I know I should write header file according to source files now.
but there are so many files. Is there any way to generate header file automatic in batches?

Comment: Not in a general way. There may be some for some particular cases; but they're normal source files.